# Orbeon: creating my own delete button

Tags: orbeon

2/28: Seems the Go uri is only if you create your own persisten layer.  I'm going to try and use a link on my form to do this.  If I can figure out how to find the form_id of the current form.

Original Question:
I'm trying to restrict who can delete a form instance.   It seems if people can get to the form-runner summary page, they can click the delete button and delete a form (even if they are not allowed to do any "/orbeon/fr/hr/expense-report/edit/*"  options.

Anyone found a way around this issue.  I wonder if we could use the GO button on the form /edit/ view to build our own delete feature.

If I look at the page source from the hr/expense-report/edit/f36b446c3ddbf7c63ec033d5c6fa7ce4 view, that the from does have the details to the actual form instance.

Example:

```
form id="xforms-form" class="xforms-form xforms-initially-hidden xforms-layout-nospan" action="/orbeon/fr/Test/Hidden_Search/edit/f36b446c3ddbf7c63ec033d5c6fa7ce4"
```

I wonder if that information could be passed to the "GO" button, if I have that on my page?

Comment: More details: From the documentation:    * The go URI, if you have enabled the go button. When the "go" button is pressed, users will be taken to the URI specified by the following property. The value of the property is an XPath expression evaluated in the context of the form instance.   Does anyone know if there is an XPath expression for the ID of the current form?  (The f36b446c3ddbf7c63ec033d5c6fa7ce4 part from my previous post)

Answer (score 0):

Right now, if users can access the Form Runner summary page, they can also access the "delete" button. Showing the "delete" button on the summary page for some users but not others, requires a change to Form Runner, which shouldn't very complicated.

For instance, if you only want the "delete" button to be shown for users with the role `can-delete`, on [this `xforms:bind` of `fr/summary/view.xhtml`](https://github.com/orbeon/orbeon-forms/blob/06c4805330fc74d1ee9f4bfdb245b8f29c16cd09/src/resources/apps/fr/summary/view.xhtml#L110) add the attribute:

```
relevant="xxforms:is-user-in-role('can-delete')"
```